# layout issue during page load when using twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am not sure if my question title is correct, but would really appreciate if someone could visit this link:

http://www.dreamsmedia.org/lasergrc/

If you noticed, when page loads, the pink navigation menu on top appears to be longer in height and adjusts once page loading is complete. I have tried to find the reason for this happening but still not able to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

have found a simple solution by giving a height to the nav element.